# HTML canvas measureText() - values differ in Chrome/Firefox

Tags: html5-canvas

When using the measureText() method on the HTML canvas, there is a difference according to which browser is used. Chrome does it properly, Firefox seems to round it somehow.

```
var input_length = context.measureText("measurethistext").width
```

- Chrome gives me a value of 70.5859375
- Firefox give me a value of 73

Any ideas how to fix this in Firefox?

**update**:

context.font is set at "12px Consolas"

Comment: Are both browsers configured to use the same fonts? My FF gives me 70.44999694824219 with its default sans-serif (seems to be Helvetica on my system).

Comment: Also, are there any other browser settings in play like font smoothing / anti aliasing? Either specifically or as browser defaults?

Comment: I assume setting 'context.font' would override default browser fonts, no? 
Maybe relevant: the context.font setting used here is "12px Consolas".
Arial gives me similar 'rounded' values in ff, not in chrome.
However, Times is not rounded in ff, but still gives slightly different values when comparing ff and chrome. Both browsers have identical settings. And I have no idea about font smoothing, anti-aliasing. I haven't changed any of the default settings concerning this.